# Is THEADS the same as FIRST?

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars, parsers, lr-k

I'm reading the paper "A Practical General Method for Constructing LR(k) Parsers" by David Pager, and it contains the following paragraph:

> We will first of all briefly review the *LR(1)* parsing and parser construction algorithms. In this paper the symbols of a grammar are denoted by Roman letters while Greek letters are employed to denote strings. $\epsilon$ is the null-string. $\alpha \Rightarrow^* \beta$ means $\beta$ is derivable from $\alpha$ (which is considered to be true if $\beta = \alpha$). By *THEADS($\alpha$)* we refer to the set $\{b \mid b \text{ is the head of a terminal string derivable
> from $\alpha$}\}$.

From what I can see *THEADS* here is what is usually called *FIRST*. Is this correct? Does *THEADS* predate *FIRST*?

Comment: Some notations are not completely standard – this may be an example. If both definitions seem the same to you, just treat it as the same thing under two different names.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The reason I ask is because I don't know what terminology was standard in 1977. If $FIRST$ was standard terminology back then Pager must've been aware of it. If he was aware of it, then why did he not use $FIRST$? Is there a subtle difference (e.g. perhaps $\alpha \Rightarrow^* \epsilon$ does not mean that $\epsilon \in THEADS(\alpha)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same question in mind when reading Pager's work. I found the paper [The Edge-Pushing LR(k) Algorithm](http://hyacc.sourceforge.net/files/SER3193.pdf) by Chen and Pager, which seems to say that the two terms are indeed the same. Quoting that paper:

> The concepts of state, configuration and theads(α, k) used here are equivalent to “item set”, “item” and FIRST<sub>k</sub>(α) correspondingly in some other literature.

Note that a lot of good references on Pager (and Chen's) work can be found at [the HYACC web site.](http://hyacc.sourceforge.net/#reference)

As for why Pager uses his own terminology in his papers, I don't have an adequate explanation, but it does indeed appear that *THEADS* and *FIRST* are the same.